# CSS sprite - showing part of another image when zooming

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-sprites, zooming

I have [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU2sM.png) CSS sprite. When I try to display the first icon, it works fine, but when I set zoom to 150%, I see also small part of the second icon. This problem is on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not on Mozilla Firefox:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxtc161w/1/)

```css
div {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/O2Cp0nb.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

That's how it looks for me on 150% zoom:

[image]

Update: Chris suggested that I need to put some space between icons. So my question is: why? And why it works fine on Mozilla Firefox even without that space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different browsers may use different algorithms for rounding numbers and rendering images in certain cases. You could read some articles about it, for example — [this](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/17/sub-pixel-rendering-and-the-css-object-model.aspx).

So, when your `zoom` is `150%` and you have `29x29`px image, your browser is need to render `43.5x43.5`px image. How each version of each browser will round it? We don't know, maybe `43x43`px, maybe `44x44`px. There is [article](http://benfrain.com/background-positions-percentages-use-case-background-zoom-property/) about sprites and zoom.

I create new code snippet with two pairs of images. The first pair uses your image sprite and the second — my. I increased the Facebook image size from `29x29`px to `30x30`px. Try to zoom it. You can see they have problems on different `zoom` ratio (the first — on `150%`, the second — on `110%`—`125%`).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/uL3cp109/1/)

```css
.fb29 {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/O2Cp0nb.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px;
}

.sun29 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/O2Cp0nb.png) 0 -29px no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px;
}

.fb30 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/mRIPLXO.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
}

.sun30 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/mRIPLXO.png) 0 -30px no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb29"></div>
<div class="sun29"></div>

<div class="fb30"></div>
<div class="sun30"></div>
```

So, my advice is to add `1px` between images to be independent from different browsers rounding algorithms and browsers bugs:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/uL3cp109/3/)

```css
.fb29 {
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/dKxYwhZ.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px;
}

.sun29 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/dKxYwhZ.png) 0 -30px no-repeat;
    background-size: 29px;
}

.fb30 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/1fJyJVK.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
}

.sun30 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/1fJyJVK.png) 0 -31px no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb29"></div>
<div class="sun29"></div>

<div class="fb30"></div>
<div class="sun30"></div>
```

If you need to support old IE browsers, look into [this article](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2013/05/sprite-gaps/).

Now you could use some useful things on `gulp`/`grunt` to automatically generate sprites where you can set gap/margin between images. See [this](http://frontendbabel.info/articles/css-sprites-with-gulp/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be image interpolation or image size rounding errors.

Maybe try this:

```
background-size: 101%;
```

It's werid but works in IE 11.

Comment: Result is similar to `background-size: cover;` - doesn't work with the second icon. And on Chrome icon is cropped a bit at right and bottom. Also note that the sprite could have more icons, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mxtc161w/5/) for example - here it doesn't work at all.

Comment: `background-size` is related to image size, and sprite image size can change often, when adding new icons.

Comment: I managed to achieve [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yLbnkat8/). Not tested on Chrome. background-size is 401%, because you have 4x 29px-width icons. However, you have to adjust position of each icon individually and it's some kind of a dirty hack. Until we get proper support of zooming across browsers, i doubt there is more we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to display the first icon, it works fine, but when I set zoom to 150%, I see also small part of the second icon.

Since you have a size defined for the container, use `background-size: cover;` should correct the zooming issue for you. The will image `"cover"` the entire width or height of the container.

Comment: Now I realised that it doesn't work when I want to display the second icon: https://jsfiddle.net/mxtc161w/3/

Comment: Removing the `background-size: cover;` on this position of the sprite appears to fix it, but part of the other icon shows when zooming in. As suggested by someone else, I would recreate the sprite and increase the spacing between each icon.

Comment: But why do I need this this spacing? And why this issue appears on Chrome and IE, but not on FF? Is that just browser bug?

Comment: The spacing is only a suggestion if zooming is a concern for you. When the zoom is set at 100%, there isn't an issue. *And why this issue appears on Chrome and IE, but not on FF?* I'm not sure what the differences would be. That's why cross-browser issues are such a headache.

Comment: @Gothdo chk this link http://benfrain.com/background-positions-percentages-use-case-background-zoom-property/
may have useful reference

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using css pixels to crop a piece of a larger image. This is what i see looking at your image url.

[image]

How about using a url with the facebook icon alone set to 29x29 like this [facebook icon example](http://www.partyonthepier.ucla.edu/images/facebook_29x29.gif)?

[image]

You can also crop the facebook icon you have and set it to 29x29 with an image editor. I did it for you using Adobe Photoshop

[image: 29x29]

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. I want a solution using CSS sprites.