# When zooming on Chrome, image sprite becomes misaligned

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, zooming, css-sprites

On Chrome when you **zoom**, the icons with an image sprite become misaligned. The position seems to drop slightly as you go farther down the background image. This only happens in Chrome.

[image: View screenshot]

Here's the CSS.

```
.feature-icon {
    height: 22px; 
    width: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url(feature-icon-sprite.png);
    background-size: 22px;
}
.schedule {
    background-position: 0 0; 
}
.selections {
    background-position: 0 -22px; 
}
.messages 
    background-position: 0 -44px; 
}
...
```

Here's the HTML.

```
<span class="feature-icon schedule"></span>
<span class="feature-icon selections"></span>
<span class="feature-icon messages"></span>
```

I've seen articles around the internet like [this](https://benfrain.com/background-positions-percentages-use-case-background-zoom-property/). Sounds like it's some pixel rounding issue with zooming in Chrome. I've tried changing the size to 20px to avoid the issue, but it still happens when zooming 110%.

Comment: Can you please post working url.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGMwbm

When changing zoom to 50% or beyond (zooming out), other parts of the sprite can be seen. I've noticed that it affects REM units much more so than px, but it might also be dependent on the image size.

Comment: @MokonaModoki In that codepen, it seems to be fixed by adding `background-size:300%;` to the `.thumbs-up-image` class.

Comment: Could you please share with us the URL, which having the issue!!

Comment: 1) My codepen from the previous comment, having issues with zoom of 50% or less: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGMwbm ; 2) One of the links listed in the question: https://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/Cctvl

Comment: @MokonaModoki, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255324/css-sprite-showing-part-of-another-image-when-zooming

Answer (score 4):

I think you could add a background size with auto to fix this issue. This works for me.

```
.thump {
  background-size: auto 100%; 
}
```

This only works when all your icons align in one row or column.(when column, it should be: `100% auto`). More like the formula below:

```
background-size: auto 100%/(rows);

background-size: 100%/(columns) auto;
```

With this style, your background image would fix into the div as you want.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Messing with the background size did help. Please note that the codepen example is much more simple than the actual page markup and the only thing that did make a difference was messing with bgsize.

Answer (score 0):

The full version of the image seems to be three 'Thumbs up' next to each other. You can replace the sprite element with the following (I tried this based on the example you provided, and this scales excellently):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,yourbase64stringhere" >
```

Now all you need to do is hide part of the image (e.g. the 66,6% on the right). For this you can use a [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), or you can just cut off the sprite so that there is only one thumbs up icon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like setting background size to auto for `.feature-icon` will work:

```
.feature-icon {
  background-size: auto;
}
```

Image is not becoming misaligned, but maybe you have not provided all necessary CSS to check it.

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5zc77d8/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem when adding

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

to the codepen...